# Certain routes go to 404 error page express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am setting up my first node project. I had all the pages working nicely until I started to move some thing around. I have done all of my routing for different pages in `index.js`. I have changed that and created a `login.js` file within my rotes folder to break up some of the logic. Before, all urls were working and displaying pages correctly. Post refactoring, I keep getting 404 page not found errors for all of the login routes.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');
//Using firebase initialized in config file.
var database = require('./config/firebase');
var app = express();


///Setting stuff up here .....

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/login', login);

app.use(function(req,res){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf();
var firebase = require('firebase');
var login = require('./login'); 


//tell express: All routes should be protected by csrf protection.
router.use(csrfProtection);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

login.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf();
//Using firebase initialized in config file.
var database = require('../config/firebase');

router.use(csrfProtection);

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
});

router.get('/forgotpassword', function (req,res){
    res.render('forgotpassword', {title:'Forgot Password'})
});

//ADD A TERMS PAGE TO SHOW TERMS AND CONDITIONS
router.get('/signup', function (req,res){
    res.render('signup', {title:'Sign up', csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The `index.js` is rendering the home view properly. Rest of the routes, like /login, or /signup are all going to 404 and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: The problem is `var csrfProtection = csrf();`, you are calling as a function. Instead try `var csrfProtection = csrf;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
app.use('/login', login);
```

You're telling Express that all requests starting with `/login` should be passed to the "login" router.

In that router, any URL's that you want to handle should be relative to that `/login` prefix (this is also *somewhat* explained [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router)).

In other words, if you want to add a handler for `/login` itself, you need to add this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { ... });
```

This will also present an issue for you, because if I understand you correctly, you also want a handler for `/signup`, which you cannot create from a router that is already prefixed with `/login`. In your case, your router is creating a handler for `/login/signup`.

You're going to need a separate router to handle `/signup`, and attach it to the main app like this:

```
app.use('/signup', signup);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. Still new to this, and I had missed that these things were relative. Makes sense. I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually so I had another follow on question...if i then try to redirect to another ('/') route which I want to be just my home screen, I would run into issues correct?Like If i wanted my signup to redirect to the / route indicated in the index.js file how would i do that?

Comment: @mufc redirection uses the full path name, so you can use `res.redirect('/signup')` (from any route).