# Node.js server stops responding until control c is pressed, works for a while afterwards then repeats this, how can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I created a node.js server that runs on AWS EC2 windows server 2016 and is run through cmd, it is used for register, sign in, (connected with a mysql database that is run on the same server) and streaming music.

This has occurred when signing in and when trying to stream music, it has basically occurred in both get and post, so I don't think that is the cause.

the code in question:

```
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var randtoken = require('rand-token');
var fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "philip",
  password: "blockchain",
  database: "blockchainDB"
});

app.post('/api/login', function(req, res){

  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
  var valP = req.headers["username"];
  var valU = req.headers["password"];
  console.log('name: ' + valP, ' pass: ' + valU);

  con.query(sql, [valP, valU], function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.json({result: 'Something went wrong (error)'});
    if(result[0] == undefined) res.json({Login: 'Failed!'});
    else{
      console.log(result[0].name);
      const user = { id: result[0].name };
      const token = jwt.sign({ user }, 'blockchain');
      res.json({
        login: 'Success!',
        token: token,
        user: result[0].name
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/api/register', function(req, res){
  //auth user
  var hash = randtoken.generate(16);
  var sql = 'INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, surname, email, dateOfBirth, password,username,cellphone,isActivated,emailHash) VALUES ?';
  var val = [[
    req.headers["id"],
    req.headers["fname"],
    req.headers["lname"],
    req.headers["email"],
    req.headers["birthdate"],
    req.headers["password"],
    req.headers["username"],
    req.headers["cellphone"],
    0,
    hash
  ]];

  con.query(sql, [val], function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.json({
          registered: 'failed',
          error: err
        });
    console.log('inserted val: ' + val);
    var link = hash;
    var emailAddress = req.headers['email'];
    var email = require('./app/email')(link,emailAddress);
    res.json({
      registered: 'Success!'
    });
  });
});

app.get('/api/protected', ensureToken, function(req, res){
  jwt.verify(req.token, 'blockchain', function(err, data){
    if(err){
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }
    else {
      var sql = 'SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE NOT name IS NULL;';
      con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields, rows){
        if (err) res.json({
          result: err
        });
        res.json({
          result: result
        });
      });
    }
  })
});

app.get('/music', function(req,res){

    var songName = req.query.song;
  var songAlbum = req.query.album;
  var songArtist = req.query.artist;
    var file = __dirname + '/music/' + songArtist + '/' + songAlbum + '/' + songName + '.mp3';
    fs.exists(file,function(exists){
        if(exists)
        {
            var rstream = fs.createReadStream(file);
            rstream.pipe(res);
        }
        else
        {
            res.send("Its a 404");
            res.end();
        }

    });
});


function ensureToken(req, res, next){
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authentication"];
  if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined'){
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('App is listening on port 8080!');
});
```

It works perfectly fine when, as stated above, and it seems to happen at totally random times, I'm still fairly new to node.js, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Usually this is a sign of an open db connection. Make sure it is closed

Comment: Instead of `mysql.createConnection`, use `mysql.createPool`.

Comment: @robertklep What will that change exactly? If you don't mind elaborating?

Comment: @user2890149 instead of creating a single connection, it creates a [connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328251/certain-routes-go-to-404-error-page-express/42328399#42328399) (multiple connections). This will allow multiple concurrent queries to be performed. I have no idea if it helps with your issue.

Comment: @robertklep shoud, is there anything that goes with creating a pool? It hasn't fixed the problem

Comment: Does this happen while the server is active, or when it receives a new request after being idle for a while?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot While the server is active. I can be testing the server and waiting for a reply, then randomly it would just hang